# You cannot push commits for 'serena@ai.com'. You can only push commits that were committed with one of your own verified emails

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push

I am not able to push my commit to remote repository in gitlab. I have my global user.name and user.email set up by running the commands:

```
git config --global user.email "serena@ai.com"
git config --global user.name "serena"
git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit
```

When I run `git config --global -l` and. `git config -l`, it does show my credentials.

I've also tried to delete my local repository and re-download. Nothing worked for me. Anyone has any suggestion to solve this ?

Add complete traceback:

```
Enumerating objects: 9, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 419 bytes | 419.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: GitLab: You cannot push commits for 'serena@ai.com'. You can only push commits that were committed with one of your own verified emails.
To https://gitlab.beno.ai/example.git
 ! [remote rejected] TIDTA-94 -> TIDTA-94 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.beno.ai/example.git'
```

Comment: What are the verified emails listed on your account?

Comment: @CarlNorum It is serena@ai.com

Comment: Show the complete error output, please? Did you clone with the matching credentials?

Comment: @CarlNorum I added the complete error output in the question. I did not clone with credentials, only with http.

Comment: This kind of checking is done by pre-receive hooks (and it shows that in the output). Those are set up by a repository's administrator, they can do anything. If they don't like your commits, they can reject them. Talk to the repo admin to see how this one works.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to answer, but the real reason behind this problem is that

**the commit** was done with unauthorized e-mail, and we you push, GIT checks the **already commited** GIT configuration, and not to the configuration that you have on your machine in that moment.
That's why when you change your email in git config after the commit, it still gives you the same error.

Try one of these two solutions:

- see this solution on [Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/a/1497911/1748218) that resets the author for the commit.
- Uncommit your last commit (the one that is causing the problem) and then change the git user and email, and then commit again and push.
  this should be easy with git client programmes like (GitHub Desktop, source Tree, etc)

In GitHub desktop:

1- Go to *History*, you will see your most recent commit as the first one, right click on it, and do uncommit.
Once you do that, the changes should appear again in the "*changes*" section.

2- Go to file on the upper left --> options --> Git, insert your credentials and hit save.

3- commit and push.

Answer (score -1):

I am able to push the commits with repository cloned with SSH. I cloned remote repository with HTTPS previously.